# regex with permutations and repetitions

Tags: python, regex

For the following patterns I need to capture "any-thing" (can contains any character except the sequence `\s-`), the last appearance of B and the last appearance of C in three different groups. B and C can be permuted and repeated, but only need to be captured if they appear after `\s-`.

```
any-thing
any-thing -
any-thing - K      => only captures any-thing, ignore everything after \s-
any-thing - B
any-thing - C
any-thing - B C
any-thing - C B
any-thing - B B
any-thing - C C
```

So far I have `(.*)\s-(\s+B|\s+C)*` but it doesn't work in the first two cases. The regex should work in Python.

Comment: So `any-thing` cannot contain `-`? or, it can't contain the sequence `\s-`?

Comment: check this one https://regex101.com/r/XmOa4v/1

Comment: Just wondering. What if you have `any-thing - A K` Do you expect the Regex to match the first part or ignore the whole line ?

Comment: @OsumanAAA good point, I would expect it matches only the first part before `\s-`. @Nick I've edited the question, it cannot contains the sequence `\s-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do what you want:

```
^(.*?)(?:\s-((?:\s+B|\s+C)*)|$)
```

It looks for some number of characters, followed either by `\s-` and some number (0 or more) of `B`s or `C`s or the end of line. It will match all the sample data you have provided; the first string is in group 1 and the `B`s and `C`s in group 2.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TRrHlg/2)

Comment: thanks, this works fine with all the test patterns. Although I would like to capture only the last `B` and `C` in different groups, i.e. first=`any-thing`, second=last `B`, third=last `C`. I've edited the question to clarify that point

Comment: @photonic.bean I don't think you can do that - a regex can only capture in the order characters occur in the string, so if your string ended in `C B` the second group would have to be `C` and the third `B`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t clear enough. I meant there should be two different capture groups for B and C, because in my particular case B and C are actually a bit more complex patterns. I have extended your answer to fit my needs and it works fine. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the first part can contain any character except the sequence `\s-` you might use:

`^((?:.(?!-\s))+)(?:\s-)?((?:\s+[BC])*)`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vkPNb9/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `(` Start capturing group

  - `.(?!-\s)` Match any character followed by a negative lookahead to assert if what is on the right is not `-\s`
- `)+` Close capturing group and repeat 1+ times
- `(?:\s-)?` Optinal non capturing group to match a whitespace character and a hyphen
- `(` Start capturing group

  - `(?:\s+[BC])*` Repeat 0+ times 1+ whitespace characters followed by B or C
- `)` Close capturing group

Comment: with `an -thi ng`, this regex captures the full match in the first group when should capture only `an` in the first group

Comment: @photonic.bean What is the rule why in `an -thi ng` only `an` should be captured? The string does not contains `-\s` right?

Comment: the first part cannot contain `\s-`, thus from `an -thi ng` only `an` should be captured. Also with the test string `an- thing`, using your regex the first group matches `a` instead of `an`

Comment: @photonic.bean Ah ok, then based on the accepted answer this will give you 3 groups [`^(.*?)(?:\s- (?:\s([BC]))?(?:\s([BC]))?|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/fHmKAT/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help -> \w*-\w+ ? ?-?(B| |C)*

Comment: Hmm, I tried in an online Regex editor and it worked for examples you had given. Did other solutions given  work and if so, can you let me know which? If not, can you add more diverse examples so we can look at them and identify a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this mate**

```
.*\s*-.*
```

> Explanation

- `.*` - Matches anything except new line.( Greedy mode ).
- `\s*` - Matches space zero or more times.
- `-` - Matches `-` (? makes it optional).
- `.*` - Matches anything except new line.( Greedy mode ).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XmOa4v/2)

Comment: I also want to capture B and C

Comment: for that just need to add `.*` at the end. check the updated answer.